# I am trying to change this from adding to individual chunks of code

Tags: php, sql

within this chunk of code i am trying to change it so its only one or the other, so if a user only gets the $toto they also end up getting $diff because they are being added together, how would i change it to only be one or the other? however i want $full to always be the first option and if they get $full they get full points however if not that then its either $toto or $diff however $diff has to be the second best option as its the highest points, any ideas on how this can be achieved?

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$prefix}scorehistory 

                                        SET score = score * ( ( full * {$full} ) 

                                                    + ( toto * {$toto} ) 

                                                    + ( goal_bonus * {$goal} ) 

                                                    + ( goal_diff_bonus * {$diff} ) ) 

                                        WHERE type = %d AND ranking_id = %d 

                                        AND user_id IN ( {$user_ids} )"
```

Comment: taking the score calculation logic outside the db query and calculating it via php would be much easier and easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Ammadu mentions, this kind of logic is usually done in the application layer and not in the database layer.

That said, I think you can do this, by using a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement. As your question is not completely clear, I can only give you an idea what you could do with it:

```
UPDATE {$prefix}scorehistory
  SET score = score * (
    CASE
      WHEN {$full} > 0 THEN full * {$full}
      WHEN {$diff} > 0 THEN goal_diff_bonus * {$diff}
      WHEN {$toto} > 0 THEN toto * {$toto}
      WHEN {$goal} > 0 THEN goal_bonus * {$goal}
      ELSE 0
    END CASE
  )
  WHERE type = %d
    AND ranking_id = %d 
    AND user_id IN ( {$user_ids} )
```

Comment: thanks for that but it didnt seem to work i tried using the logic but i cannot achieve the implementing part

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to change this chunk of code so that if the player gets goal difference and toto score they only get the goal difference, however the rules should be the $full should always be first option and $diff should be second best option, and $toto should be last option, this is so if the user cant get full points it checks for second best score and last best score so they have a chance of getting something, here is the chunk of code.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$prefix}scorehistory 

                                        SET score = score * ( ( full * {$full} ) 

                                                    + ( toto * {$toto} ) 

                                                    + ( goal_bonus * {$goal} ) 

                                                    + ( goal_diff_bonus * {$diff} ) ) 

                                        WHERE type = %d AND ranking_id = %d 

                                        AND user_id IN ( {$user_ids} )"

                                        , FOOTBALLPOOL_TYPE_MATCH, $calculate_this_ranking );
```